# Rendering lightweight markup languages with maven

Tags: java, maven, markdown, markup, textile

I would like to render project documentation in html from a [lighweight markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language) like markdown or textile. What's easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maven site plugin is able to render the APT format ("Almost Plain Text") to build html for the project (documentation) site.

@See:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html

http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/apt-format.html

Answer (score 4):

You can also use other lightweight markup languages with the maven-site-plugin. This is done through [doxia](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/index.html) (maven's content generation framework). There is a doxia module for markdown, for example:

http://code.google.com/p/doxia-module-markdown/wiki/Usage